# What is the best way to iterate objects using linq

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

```
           var AddQuery = from newdist in newSpec.Distributions
               where !( from oldDist in oSpec.Distributions
               select oldDist.Id).Contains( newdist.Id )
               select newdist;

          foreach (var dist in AddQuery)
          {
            dist.operation="Add";
          }
          var updateQuery = from oldDistributionForUpdate in ospec.Distributions
                            where (from newDistributionForUpdate in newspec.Distributions
                            select newDistributionForUpdate.DistributionId).Contains(oldDistributionForUpdate.DistributionId)
                            &&
                            (from newDistributionForUpdate in newpaymentSpecification.Distributions
                            select newDistributionForUpdate.Amount).Equals(oldDistributionForUpdate.Amount)
                            select oldDistributionForUpdate;

          foreach (var dist in updateDistQuery)
          {
            dist.operation = "Update";
          }
```

I am planning to have a collection of objects from both the query results & process them, Is there a simpler way to achieve what I am doing?

Comment: I think the way you are iterating over the collection is the easiest way to do it. You could do `AddQuery.ToList().ForEach(i => i.operation = "Add")`

Answer (score 0):

In your original snippet, you are matching on `Id` for `AddQuery` and on `DistributionId` for `UpdateQuery`. If this is a typo and it should be `Id` or `DistributionId` for both cases, then you can process Add and Update much more efficiently in the same loop.

```
var AddUpdateQuery = from newdist in newSpec.Distributions
                         join oldDist in oSpec.Distributions
                         on newdist.Id equals oldDist.Id into matchingDistributions
                         select new { newdist, matchingDistributions };

    foreach (var dist in AddUpdateQuery)
    {
        if (!dist.matchingDistributions.Any())
        {
            dist.newdist.operation = "Add";
            //additional processing for "Add" operation.
        }
        else if (dist.newdist.Amount == dist.matchingDistributions.First().Amount)
        {
            dist.newdist.operation = "Update";
            //additional processing for "Update" operation.
        }
    }
```